# Using os.walk to create discord.py cog names

Tags: python, discord.py, os.walk

I'm trying to automate my discord.py bot's scan and intake of cogs as extentions using `os.walk`
and I'd like to understand why checking for cogs after the bot is live says none are loaded.
I'm a little new to python and learning as I go so please forgive any times I need an answer expanding on.

This is the portion of the script that is responsible for the operation

```py
### COGS ###
@bot.event
async def setup_hook():
    for dirs in next(os.walk('.'))[1]:
        for i in range(len(dirs)):
            if dirs[i].startswith("."):
                for file in os.listdir(''.join(dirs[i])):
                    if file.endswith(".py"):
                        await bot.load_extension(f"{dirs[i]}.{file[:-3]}")
    print('Cogs should be done now.')
```

As I understood it, taking the second part of os.walk would return the folder names in the same directory as the .py script running it, so `next(os.walk('.'))[1]` was meant to populate a list `dirs` with the folders present in the root folder.
I hoped that I could basically do a for loop on those folders and get the names of the python files and append the folder and python script names to each other with `(f"{dirs[i]}.{file[:-3]}")` to create the dot qualified names of them.

edit:
I was trying to get every extension in a given folder, but they're organised further into folders.
So while I want it to be a case of `/src/cogs/allthecogs.py` I actually have `src/coggroup1/type1cogshere.py` and `src/coggroup2/type2cogshere.py`

I've since relegated them to camelCased names in one folder and I'm just running this:

```
for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

Admittedly, there are now new problems, but I think I was overdoing it to make it human readable at the cost of more work.

Comment: That's a terrible practice.  Just do `os.listdir` and check each name for `os.path.isdir`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Wouldn't I then need to pass the results to another `os.listdir` to get the py file names too? I'm writing it up now I'm just curious if there's a benefit to this over iterating a list from `os.walk`. Like I said, new to py so I'm happy to learn what is and isn't bad practice, just curious as to the why and why not.

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to do that anyway.  Are you trying to grab all files with a given extension that are one-level deep, or are you trying to grab all files with that extension no matter how deeply nested they are?

Comment: @TimRoberts Edited for clarity, I wasn't as verbose in the main post as I maybe could have been. Lesson learned. Thank you for your advice though, it did help me realise I was making my job harder for no reason.